# rails 4: put models in subdirectories but without namespacing ( only to organise )

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, models, organization, subdirectory

What would be the way to do this in rails 4?

For Rails 3 this works:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[ Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**/') ]
```

But in Rails 4 it fails complaining about namespacing non existent ( like 
`app/models/users/credits.rb` gives error

```
Unable to autoload constant User::Credits, expected
```

Comment: See the "Update for Rails 4.1" section of the accepted anser at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934115/rails-4-organize-rails-models-in-sub-path-without-namespacing-models

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and fixed it by adding this to `application.rb`.

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```